# No deviceready event fired with cordova-android 6.1.2?

Tags: android, cordova

On a new project, it seems I do not get the deviceready event fired with cordova-android 6.1.2 as it used to be in previous versions of Cordova.

I do not have any plugin installed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Project</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log('deviceready');
      }
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    </script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference Cordova.js like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src='Path_Of_Folder/Cordova.js>
```

Replace Path_Of_Folder with your path.

Comment: Erf... Indeed that was it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Easy mistake. 